# Executing Robotscripts on Mac Safari browser is strange

Tags: robotframework

I developed a Testsuite with 2 testcases one with valid scenario and other with invalid scenario.

#### Testcase1

Teststeps:

- Launch url
- Login with valid credentials(used locators xpath=ID for username and password)
  perform some clicks and do some verifications
- Logout
- close browser

#### Testcase2

TestSteps:

- Launch url
- Login with invalid password(used locators xpath=ID)
- verify the error message
- Close browser

When i execute this Testsuite on Windows and test run on Chrome / Firefox both the testcases run successfully.

But when i run on Mac Safari only the first testcase(either 1 or 2) gets executed  and other testcase fails. Don't understand the reason. I tried sych up scripts to application. But don't understand the underlying reason.

Appreciate if someone could help here or seen such scenario? Testcase fails because of invalid xpath/ or element not found

On same Mac Chrome both the testcases(1 and 2) run without interruption.

Comment: Could you try to improve the formatting of your question? Your test steps appear to be a list of steps, but appears as a single paragraph.

Comment: Have you verified that the browser actually closes after the first step, or could the close be silently failing so it's reusing the old browser?

Comment: Do you have a specific error message text you can share?

Comment: @Kootstra, Because of the  Safari browser sometimes gets closed sometimes not during different test runs hence i find NoSuchElement/ ElementNotVisible  etc. even after specifying some 'Sleep' before and after an action.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley, I tried all possible ways to close the browser and to reopen at Suite level and Testcase level (after each testcase) but Chrome browser automatically gets closed without any issues on Mac but Safari on Mac doesn't nor opens another instance when i mention 'Open browser @ Testsetup before staring another testcase. Don't understand how to handle. The Safari behavior is not consistent at each run.